# Mouse-Clicking on Specific Window / Background Window (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this neat library, [robotjs](http://robotjs.io/). You can simulate key presses, mouse clicks, and more. I was wondering if it were possible to click the mouse at a specific x,y position on a background window. I'm not specifically looking for a [robotjs](http://robotjs.io/) solution to this. Any other libraries (or native js itself) will work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to that yet?

Answer (score -3):

The [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function can accept an event as a parameter, so you can create you own positioned click:

```
var event = $.Event('click');
event.clientX = 100;
event.clientY = 50;
$('div').trigger(event);
```

Comment: I'm looking for a nodejs answer

Comment: So the real problem is not just to click on a specific position since robotjs is doing this easily but rather to click on a BACKGROUND window at a specific position. Am I right?